# circle buffer for serial port in c#

Tags: c#

I want to creating circle buffer in c#.
i have Arduino board that sending a lot of data 
when discard buffer in serial port command some of data will be lost.
at this situation I need circle buffer for my data to ricived  them .

```
InputData = ComPort.ReadByte();
object firstByte = InputData;

if (ComPort.IsOpen==true)
{
    s = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToChar(firstByte));
    temp1 += s;
    lock (firstByte) {    
    if (Convert.ToInt32( firstByte)== 13)
    {
        temp = temp1;
        temp1 = "";                   
        LstGetInfo.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>
        { 
            if (temp !=null)
            { 
                LstGetInfo.Items.Add(temp);

                if (LstGetInfo.Items.Count >= 100)
                {
                     LstGetInfo.Items.Clear();
                     // ComPort.DiscardInBuffer();
                     //ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
                }
                FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Append);
                var data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format("{0} {1}", temp, DateTime.Now.ToString("hh mm ss")) +"\r\n");
                fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
        }));
        LstGetInfo.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            LstGetInfo.TopIndex = LstGetInfo.Items.Count - 1;
        }));
    }
}
```

any solution for this problem ?

Comment: be careful, it's probably best *not* to name a variable `var` in C#, since it's also used like this : `var banana = true`

Comment: Also, if someone edits your code to make it readable, don't throw away their edits, they are trying to help

Comment: I don't see the thrown-away edit in the history.  OP added the word "and" to your edit.

Comment: I usually create a FIFO using a List<> object.  I add new info at end using Add() method and remove using RemoveRange(0, length);  and get data using Substring(0, length);

Comment: sorry 
I am not  familer with user interface of this site

Comment: @jdweng can you explain how can i do ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;


namespace ConsoleApplication72
{
    class Program
    {

        static string buffer = "";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }

        static void AddToBuffer(byte[] rxData)
        {
            buffer += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(rxData);
        }
        static string ReadLine()
        {
            int returnIndex = buffer.IndexOf("\n");
            if (returnIndex >= 0)
            {
                string line = buffer.Substring(0, returnIndex);
                buffer = buffer.Remove(0, returnIndex + 1);
                return line;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `buffer = buffer.Remove(0, returnIndex + 1)`

Comment: Code is a very simple FIFO.  Adds receive data to end of FIFO.  Removes one line of data terminated with a return from the fifo.